# Fastest way to calculate the the difference from previous value in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the fastest way to calculate the difference with previous value in an array with javascript.

```
var arr = [10,20,30,40,50];
```

I want to obtain the following result (10-20,20-30,30-40,40-50)

Comment: For what reason "fastest"? How many microseconds would you like to save for 4 differences?

Comment: For knowledge. To know different ways to do that.

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = arr.map(function(x,i) {
    return x - arr[i+1]
}).filter(Number);

// result - [-10, -10, -10, -10]
```

```js
var arr = [10,20,30,40,50]; 

var result = arr.map(function(x,i) {
    return x - arr[i+1]
}).filter(Number);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var results = [];
var arr = [10,20,30,40,50]; 

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
results.push(arr[i] - arr[i+1]);
}
```

See it in [action](https://jsfiddle.net/tus7oc20/1/)

Comment: `-` has to be in quotes, `results.push(arr[i] + '-' + arr[i+1]);`

Comment: No, it hasn't to be quotes he wants the difference!